# Python - delete blank lines of text at the end of the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script that modifies any text files. It replaces white space lines with blank lines. It erases the blank lines at the end of the file. The image shows the output I want.

[image]

I am able to get very close to the desired output. The problem is that I cannot get rid of the last blank line. I think this has something to do with the last line. e.g `' the lines below me should be gone` actually looks like this `' the lines below me should be gone\n'` It looks like new lines are created on the previous line. e.g if line 4 has `\n` than line 5 will actually be the blank line not line 4.

I should note that I can't use `rstrip` or `strip`

My code so far.

```
def clean_file(filename):
    # function to check if the line can be deleted
    def is_all_whitespace(line):
        for char in line:
            if char != ' ' and char != '\n':
                return False
        return True

    # generates the new lines
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        file_out = []
        for line in file:
            if is_all_whitespace(line):
                line = '\n'
            file_out.append(line)

    # removes whitespaces at the end of file
    while file_out[-1] == '\n':  # while the last item in lst is blank
        file_out.pop(-1)  # removes last element

    # writes the new the output to file
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write(''.join(file_out))

clean_file('test.txt')
```

Comment: You've done a lot of research on this question and it's very clear. +1.

Comment: Why "can't" you use `.rstrip()`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that would be too easy

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\n` essentially means "create another line"

So when you've removed all the lines that are `\n`, there's still the preceding line

```
the lines below me should be gone\n
```

Which again means "create another line", beyond the ones you've already removed

Since you say you can't use `rstrip`, you could end the loop with

```
file_out[-1] = file_out[-1].strip('\n')
```

to remove `\n` from the last element. Because `\n` can't exist anywhere else in a line, `rstrip` and `strip` will have the same effect

Or without *any* `strip` or `endswith`:

```
if file_out[-1][-1] == '\n':
    file_out[-1] = file_out[-1][:-1]
```

Note that `\n` is a single character, ordinal `0x0a` as hex, *not* two characters `\` and `n`, ordinals `0x5c` and `0x6e`. That is why we use `-1` and not `-2`

Comment: @Vader Then I suspect you can use `file_out[-1][-1] == '\n'`.

Comment: @Vader Why did you think to use `-2`? `'\n'` is one character.

Comment: @Vader `'\n'` is **one** character that says "newline". The backslash (`'\')` is an escape to distinguish it from a regular `'n'`.

Comment: @Vader So that it is not confused by the parser as a regular `'n'`. When escaped, what you see as `'\n'` is read by the parser as one single character, namely the "newline" character, and NOT a slash and an "n".

Comment: @Vader Right. Another example is the null character. `'\0'` is **not** two characters of slash and zero, but a single byte of integral value `0` (and not the character zero, either).

Comment: answer edited. this is a lot of comments; maybe delete them if you're finished?